# AppDelegate methods not being invoked

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I am trying to make a jabber chat application using the xmppframework.
I have implemented the xmppStream methods in the applicationAppDelegate, but none of these method has been invoked.

Here is the code of the applicationAppDelegate:

```
    - (void)setupStream {
    xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
    [xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    //[self connect];
}
- (void)goOnline {
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence];
    [[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
}
- (void)goOffline {
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presenceWithType:@"unavailable"];
    [[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
}

- (BOOL)connect {
    [self setupStream];


    NSString *emailUserDefault = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"email"];

    NSString *jabberID = [emailUserDefault stringByAppendingString:@"@server.local"];
    NSLog(@"%@",jabberID);
    NSString *myPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"password"];
    NSLog(@"%@",myPassword);

    if (![xmppStream isDisconnected]) {
        NSLog(@"You are connected");

        return YES;
    }
    if (jabberID == nil || myPassword == nil) {
        return NO;
    }
    [xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:jabberID]];
    //xmppStream.myJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:jabberID];
    password = myPassword;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![xmppStream connectWithTimeout:20 error:&error])
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can't connect to server %@", [error localizedDescription]]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
- (void)disconnect {
    [self goOffline];
    [xmppStream disconnect];
}
- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender {
    isOpen = YES;
    NSError *error = nil;
    [[self xmppStream] authenticateWithPassword:password error:&error];
}
- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender {
    [self goOnline];
}
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence {
    NSString *presenceType = [presence type]; // online/offline
    NSString *myUsername = [[sender myJID] user];
    NSString *presenceFromUser = [[presence from] user];
    if (![presenceFromUser isEqualToString:myUsername]) {
        if ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"available"]) {
            [__chatDelegate newBuddyOnline:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", presenceFromUser, @"server.local"]];
        } else if ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"unavailable"]) {
            [__chatDelegate buddyWentOffline:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", presenceFromUser, @"server.local"]];
        }
    }
}
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message {
    NSString *msg = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
    NSString *from = [[message attributeForName:@"from"] stringValue];
    NSMutableDictionary *m = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [m setObject:msg forKey:@"msg"];
    [m setObject:from forKey:@"sender"];
    [__messageDelegate newMessageReceived:m];

}
```

Here my code for the chatViewController classe:

```
- (myApplicationAppDelegate *)appDelegate {
    return (myApplicationAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
- (XMPPStream *)xmppStream {
    return [[self appDelegate] xmppStream];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    onlineBuddies = [[NSMutableArray alloc ] init];
    myApplicationAppDelegate *del = [self appDelegate];
    [self xmppStream];
    NSString *login = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"email"];
    del._chatDelegate = self;
    if (login) {
        if ([[self appDelegate] connect]) {
            NSLog(@"show buddy list");
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Login Error");
    }

}
```

I cannot figure out why the xmpp delegate methods are not being invoked. If someone can give me a hand, please don't hesitate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the purpose of `AppDelegate`. First of all for every iOS app that you are creating in `Xcode` there is a class created that contains the name `AppDelegate` but this class should only be used to get information of your application state, such as if the app goes to background, if it's launched with success or if it's coming up from background. Also the app delegate is used to specify the root (or entry point) view controller of your application.

So I think you should first check the basic rules (or a basic tutorial) on how to create a very simple application (a "Hello World Application"), after that you can go forward and create a basic structure of your application and decide what view controller or what model classes will handle your connection handling and response/request parsing.

I strongly suggest that you have a look over view controllers and I'm pretty sure that after you do the above suggested "tasks" you will answer yourself the posted question.

P.S Last point, have a look on "iOS naming & other conventions"[enter link description here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html)[life cycle methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html)